# Jquery UI slider : slide and stop options calling several functions?

Tags: function, slide, jquery-ui-slider

I'm making slider for changing the opacity of a element and I created function for saving opacity value in localStorage and a function for creating a tooltip in hover of slider handle. But my problem is I don't know to use both in same time.

Here is part of my script :

```
 slider.slider({
    range: "max", 
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    step: 0.01,
    slide:[opacityOperate, sliderTooltip],
    stop:[opacityRegister, sliderTooltip]// avoid storing non-final data
});
```

I did not find in Jquery UI doc how to write for calling several functions and `slide:[opacityOperate, sliderTooltip],` looks wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could call `sliderTooltip()` both from `opacityOperate()` and `opacityRegister()`.

Comment: Okay, except this solution what I want isn't possible? I'd really like to keep nice and clean structure that I made.

Comment: Nope, you cannot pass several handlers this way in jQuery UI (at least for now).